# Changing packet routing policy on Ubuntu server

Tags: networking, router

I'm using Ubuntu server on a router and I'm facing the following problem. If one person starts a download that is able to take all the bandwidth, it does. Which means, all other people start experiencing problems using the internet.

Is there a way (with iptables, tc or whatever) to make the router give higher priority to packets from connections with lower bandwidth? So that this high bandwidth downloads won't overtake other connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `tc` to shape your traffic. For example, you can set a limit on the allowed download/upload speed to each IP address in the network. There are several queuing options to allow different configurations. Maybe, you can try to use the [SFQ](http://linux-ip.net/articles/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/classless-qdiscs.html#qs-sfq) (stochastic fair queuing).

For more details, you can look at the [advanced Linux routing website](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/) and see `man tc`.

Comment: I prefer not using limits. Instead, is it possible to have one queue for each connection and the resource is allocated for one queue at a time? I'm not sure if I made myself clear, but I just want all the connections to have equal access to the network. We don't have p2p, so i think a policy like this would work.